# How to check if a string has same characters in same order, but other string has extra characters in Java

Tags: java

So basically I have to check if another string has the same characters in the same order.

[image]

So if the blood has same letters in same order as coronavirus like second one, I have to print positive. How to do this in Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Where is the string to be compared against?

Comment: The second one crnas

Comment: With coronavirus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to make use of the [String#indexOf()](https://www.baeldung.com/string/index-of) method and a boolean flag, for example:

```
String mainString = "caronavirus";
String[] stringsToCompare = {"abcde", "crnas", "aovrs", "onarous"};
    
System.out.println("INPUT\n=====");
System.out.println(mainString);
System.out.println(stringsToCompare.length);
for (String wStrg : stringsToCompare) {
    System.out.println(wStrg);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("OUTPUT\n======");

System.out.println(mainString);
System.out.println(stringsToCompare .length);
for (String wStrg : stringsToCompare) {
    int idx = 0;
    boolean isNegative = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < wStrg.length(); i++) {
        String ch = wStrg.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (mainString.indexOf(ch, idx) >= idx) {
            idx = mainString.indexOf(ch, idx);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NEGATIVE");
            isNegative = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isNegative) {
        System.out.println("POSITIVE");
    }
}
```

The console window display should look something like:

```
INPUT
=====
caronavirus
4
abcde
crnas
aovrs
onarous


OUTPUT
======
NEGATIVE
POSITIVE
POSITIVE
NEGATIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a regex out of each string you want to test against your main string. For example `crnas` should be transformed to `.*c.*r.*n.*a.*s.*` which then you can use with the `String.matches` method which returns a boolean. `coronavirus.matches(".*c.*r.*n.*a.*s.*")` will for example return true. To give you a starting point:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String mainString    = "coronavirus";
        String[] testStrings = {"abcde", "crnas", "onarous"};

        for(String test : testStrings){
            System.out.println(test + " : " + (mainString.matches(toRegex(test)) ? "POSITIVE" : "NEGATIVE"));
        }
    }

    static String toRegex(String input){
        return Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(".*", ".*", ".*"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abcde : NEGATIVE
crnas : POSITIVE
onarous : NEGATIVE
```